# Как сделать все объекты на одной строке?

Tags: html, css

У меня такого не было, что применяя данные css свойства, заголовки были лесенкой, я пытался это как-то исправить, но как?
P.s. Вот нужный код:
HTML:

```
<div class="Project">
        <h1 class=h11>Projects</h1>
        <div class="Example">
            <div class="name">
                <h1 class="z1">01 Example</h1>
                <h1 class="z2">02 Example</h1>
                <h1 class="z3">03 Example</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.Example {
    margin-top: 250px;
}

.z1 {
    float: left;
}

.z2 {
    margin-right: 700px;
    margin-left: 700px;
}

.z3 {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот таким способом:

```css
.Example {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.name {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Project">
  <h1 class=h11>Projects</h1>
  <div class="Example">
    <div class="name">
      <h1 class="z1">01 Example</h1>
      <h1 class="z2">02 Example</h1>
      <h1 class="z3">03 Example</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```